# Eloquent SELECT from UNION result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two different tables with the (almost) the same structure:
(not the best DB design, but unfortunately out of my control)

**Table A:**

```
+-----------+------+-------+-----+
| client_id | year | month | fee |
+-----------+------+-------+-----+
|       33  |   11 |  2022 |  11 |
|       42  |   11 |  2022 |  13 |
|       33  |   12 |  2022 |  27 |
|       16  |   12 |  2022 |  15 |
+-----------+------+-------+-----+
```

**Table B:**

```
+-----------+------+-------+-----+
| client_id | year | month | fee |
+-----------+------+-------+-----+
|       33  |   11 |  2022 |  19 |
|       57  |   11 |  2022 |  34 |
+-----------+------+-------+-----+
```

I want to **SUM** fees of all clients grouping bu month and year.

For one table the eloquent query is simple:

```
$queryA = DB::table('A')
    ->selectRaw('month, year, COUNT(*) AS total, SUM(fee) AS total_fee')
    ->groupBy(['month', 'year']);
```

(`$queryB` will be the same, with `->table('B')` instead ).

In order to get total sum of both tables, I want to use UNION.

**The approach:**
I want to apply a `SELECT` query on the result returned by `UNION`:

```
SELECT month, year, COUNT(*) AS total, SUM(total_fee) AS total_fee
FROM
  (
    (
      SELECT month, year, COUNT(*) AS total, SUM(fee) AS total_fee
      FROM A
      GROUP BY month, year
    ) UNION (
      SELECT month, year, COUNT(*) AS total, SUM(fee) AS total_fee
      FROM B
      GROUP BY month, year
    )
  ) AS result_table
GROUP BY month, year
ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC;
```

**The problem:**
I tried this:

```
$queryA
  ->union($queryB)
  ->select(month, year, COUNT(*) AS total, SUM(total_fee) AS total_fee)
  ->groupBy(['month', 'year'])
```

the new `SELECT` statement is inserted into the `$queryA` sub-query.

Any idea how to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: why dont use DB::raw() and write raw query in it?

Comment: @amirhoseinhadi, this is of course an option, although whenever it is possible it is safer to use eloquent code to generate the query.